# Two factorial time series mixed effect model using lmer

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data, crossed-random-effects

I'm facing a problem regarding the the selection of an appropriate model and right synthax using lmer()-command (lme4-package). But first let me explain the design of the study:

**Study design:** I ran an experiment were I measured the activity of soil samples i.e. CO2 production (=dependant variable "CO2") over time. First independant variable is the type of organism applied to soil (independant variable "organism" with the 4 levels: A / B / C /D). Second independant variable is whether or not the system is supplemented with a stimulant (independant variable "supplement" with the 2 Levels: Yes / No). So In total there are 8 treatments which are combinations of two independant factorial variables:

- A x Yes
- B x Yes
- C x Yes
- D x Yes
- A x No
- B x No
- C x No
- D x No

Each of these treatments is replicated 6 times (N=6) in isolated containers. So in total there are 6 (replicates) x 8 (treatments) = 48 containers. CO2 production in the containers is measured in 1-minute intervals for 1 week (=10080 dates).

**Study question:**
I'm interested whether (i) the type of organism, (ii) the supplement and (iii) the interaction of both have an effect on the CO2 production.

**Statistic question:** So if I understand right I have a fully crossed random effects where each container (random effect variable "container" with 48 levels) appears at each sampling date (random effect variable "time" with 10800 levels). Consequently i expect that the synthax should be:

```
lmer(CO2~organism*supplement+(organism*supplement|time)+(organism*supplement|container))
```

I could of course also just use the data from the last measurement and create a model like this:

```
lmer(CO2~organism*supplement+(organism*supplement|container))
```

However, I would prefer to use the whole data because otherwise I would lose a lot of information.

However, since this the first time I work with such a design I'm quiet unsure if I have chosen an appropriate model and synthax. So I’d be very grateful if someone could tell me if the proposed statistical method is appropriate and if yes, if the presented synthax is right. Many thanks!

Comment: What was the purpose of measuring the outcome so frequently ?

Comment: Such a high measuring frequency was not really intended or planned but rather predefined by the characteristics of the measuring instrument.

Comment: Ok. So is there any expected trend in measurements over time ?

Comment: So the following trends are expected: (i) increase of CO2 over time for all treatments, (ii) slope for increases in the order of  A<B<C<D, (iii) time-course CO2 increases in the order No<Yes, (iv) Slope is higher in the first days. However, only (ii) and (iii) are relevant for the hypotheses/study question. But since it would be nice to present the CO2 development over time, I thought it makes sense to also include the whole data for statistics. But for statistics only point (ii) and (iii) are relevant.